# How to set functions region for React Native Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, react-native-firebase

I have a react native app with react-native-firebase and I'm trying to run a callable https firebase function which is deployed to a custom region.

I've read that `firebase.app().functions("MY-REGION")` so I tried the following:

```
import { firebase } from "@react-native-firebase/database"
import functions from "@react-native-firebase/functions"

firebase.app().functions("MY-REGION")
```

But If I run that I get this error:

```
Error: You attempted to use 
"firebase.app('[DEFAULT]').functions" but this
module could not be found.

Ensure you have installed and imported the
'@react-native-firebase/functions' package
```

The functions package is installed.

If I remove the `@react-native-firebase/functions` import the error stays the same.

**How can I specify the region for firebase https functions in `react-native-firebase`?**

---

#### More attempts:

```
firebase.initializeApp({
   ...options
})

firebase.app().functions("MY-REGION")
```

And that says `Error: Firebase App named '[DEFAULT]' already exists`

```
firebase.initializeApp({
   ...options
}, "APP_NAME")

firebase.app("APP_NAME").functions("MY-REGION")
```

Gives `Error: No firebase App 'APP_NAME' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()`

---

*I hope I'm missing something trivial.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A solution is to change the functions import from `import functions from "..."` to `import "..."`:

```
import { firebase } from "@react-native-firebase/database"
import "@react-native-firebase/functions" // <--

// call a https firebase function
firebase.app().functions("MY-REGION").httpsCallable('MyFunction')()
```

Note that `MY-REGION` should be set to the region shown in the firebase functions dashboard for the selected httpsCallable function.

The fix I found was indeed quite trivial...
I've shared it here so it can be useful for others, but better solutions are welcome!

Comment: This solution worked! Thank you so much!